# Why does the Spark worker actor use a masterLock?

Tags: akka, apache-spark

As far as I know, actors only process one message at a time. I don't understand why the Apache Spark [Worker actor](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/worker/Worker.scala) synchronizes on a masterLock?

```
case SendHeartbeat =>
  masterLock.synchronized {
    if (connected) { master ! Heartbeat(workerId) }
  }
```

I would expect it to look like this:

```
case SendHeartbeat =>
    if (connected) { master ! Heartbeat(workerId)
```

Comment: If you post a link to the source, it will be easier for everyone to look it up for more context...

Comment: @pushy https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/worker/Worker.scala

Comment: I see what you mean, I have not looked too deeply into the Spark code yet, maybe there is a subtlety there I fail to see, but from what I can see I would agree with you, that it does not seem necessary...

Comment: Agree with you. Maybe you'd better sending an email to dev@spark.apache.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on the [user list thread](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-why-need-a-masterLock-when-sending-heartbeat-to-master-td12256.html). Short answer is that the lock is no longer necessary; it's just a remnant of when the master could be changed from a different thread than the actor, a poor design that was later amended.